# create Sharepoint publishing site using Client Object model

Tags: sharepoint

I want to create SharePoint publishing pages using Client object model such that I can manually set the page layout.

Basically I want to know is there any way to work like that we can do in server based programming .

```
   PageLayout[] pageLayouts = publishingWeb.GetAvailablePageLayouts(); 
   PublishingPageCollection pages = publishingWeb.GetPublishingPages();
   PublishingPage newPage = pages.Add(pageName, currPageLayout);
   newPage.ListItem.Update();
```

Comment: Do you want to create publishing page or publishing site?

Comment: i want publishing pages to create